# Strange SQL error when plain SQL put into stored procedure. Error: Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a plain SQL query like this:

```
SELECT        
   Users.userEmail AS registredEmail, 
   Status.statusName AS userActiveStatus, 
   Roles.roleName AS roleAssigned, 
   Users.userID AS uID
FROM
   Users 
INNER JOIN
   Status ON Users.userStatus = Status.statusID 
INNER JOIN
   Roles ON Users.userRole = Roles.roleID 
WHERE
   (Users.companyID = 'D77VD')
```

Since the `where` condition is a variable, put this SQL in a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_Users_12_CompanyUserGridview]
   @companyID varchar(20)
AS
   SELECT        
      Users.userEmail AS registredEmail, 
      Status.statusName AS userActiveStatus, 
      Roles.roleName AS roleAssigned, 
      Users.userID AS uID
   FROM            
      Users 
   INNER JOIN
      Status ON Users.userStatus = Status.statusID 
   INNER JOIN
      Roles ON Users.userRole = Roles.roleID
   WHERE 
      (Users.companyID = @companyID)
```

But strangely, the plain SQL with `where` value 'D77VD' runs just fine, but when I run this stored procedure and pass same value as parameter, it give me an error

> Invalid object name 'Users'

Answer (score 2):

One of these should resolve your problem.

1.Make sure that you have created the procedure in the same database (not in 'master' by mistake)
2.Try adding schema name to table 'User' like 'dbo.User' instead of simple 'User'

EX:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_Users_12_CompanyUserGridview]
@companyID varchar(20)
AS
SELECT        dbo.Users.userEmail AS registredEmail, Status.statusName AS userActiveStatus, Roles.roleName AS roleAssigned, dbo.Users.userID AS uID
FROM            dbo.Users INNER JOIN
                         Status ON dbo.Users.userStatus = Status.statusID INNER JOIN
                         Roles ON dbo.Users.userRole = Roles.roleID
WHERE (dbo.Users.companyID = @companyID)
```

If your problem still not resolved, please let me know.

Comment: +1 for you, had the same problem and spent many hours trying to get what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@Suvendu Shekhar Giri -very nice catch!

@user1889838 it is very good practice use schema name for all the joining tables .... table named Status might give an error too if not use schema name.